# What can be an example other than batch normalization that uses statistics of batches?

Tags: batch-normalization, statistics, batch-size

Consider the following paragraph, taken from **OPTIMIZING BATCHES** of the textbook named **[Deep Learning with PyTorch](https://web.archive.org/web/20220113022756/https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf)** by *Eli Stevens et al.*, regarding the reasons for processing data into batches

> The reason we want to do this batching is multifaceted. One big
> motivation is to make sure the computation we’re asking for is big
> enough to saturate the computing resources we’re using to perform the
> computation. GPUs in particular are highly parallelized, so a single
> input on a small model will leave most of the computing units idle. By
> providing batches of inputs, the calculation can be spread across the
> otherwise-idle units, which means the batched results come back just
> as quickly as a single result would. **Another benefit is that some
> advanced models use statistical information from the entire batch, and
> those statistics get better with larger batch sizes.**

The bolded portion says a statistical reason for batch processing. I know only batch normalization that satisfies the portion as mean and standard deviation are calculated over the batch of inputs.

Is there any such example that needs statistics of batches that are apt to the description?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some examples:

- [Group Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08494.pdf)
- [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf)
- [Switchable Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.10473.pdf)
- [Attentive Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.01259.pdf)
- [Spectrl Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05957.pdf)

Notice how in general different normalization techniques are implemented using as a backbone the same idea of batch normalization, i.e. computing mean and standard deviation, but along a different dimension rather than the batch one, or on a subset of points (image below taken from the switchable normalization paper)

[image]

The alternative, as performed by the attentive and spectral normalization authors, is to rethink the normalization as something different from the classic linear transformation $\mu x + \sigma$, or to add extra parameters to learn, to make the normalization more non linear (image taken from the attentive normalization paper).

[image]